# UIScrollview position moves after touches begin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I view imbedded in a Navigation Controller which is slightly transparent. This view contains a UIscrollview. This UIScrollview has the following subviews: UIImageView, UILabel, and UIWebview. All these other views are working correctly. When the view loads, everything is in the correct position (The views are below the Navigation Bar). However, as soon as the screen is tapped, the scrollview repositions itself to the top of the view (aka behind the Navigation Bar, which is at the top, and I can see that this is true because the Nav Bar is slightly transparent)

Any idea why this is happening? I set up the scrollview like this:

```
 self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.window.frame.size.width, self.view.window.frame.size.height);
```

Also set these properties:

```
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
self.scrollView.bounces = YES;
```

Anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd similar problem, but only on iOS 7.0. Try to set the `translucent = NO` property of the `navigationBar`. This will make the `navigationBar` opaque. Although if you want the `navigationBar` to be transparent, try to change the `contentInset` of the `scrollView` to adjust the content as you want. Hope that this will help :)